# Magento 2 Webhook

Tags: magento2, controllers, redirect, braintree

Can someone help me with this issue, i'm using **Braintree** webhook, which is sending post data to my **Magento 2 controller route**, but from some reason, it always redirects me to home page, giving me 302 response, and i'm unable to receive post from webhook and deal with it accordingly. I'm using apache and .htaccess but every rule that i have put in there just gives me to many redirects error.

Answer (score 0):

is it custome Magento 2 controller route? is it front-end route? 
Did you check rewrite table?

make sure rout ID and frontName are same. Don't know why but this way it works more stable.

```
<route id="fooid" frontName="fooid">
```

Comment: Yes, it is custom front-end controller route. And yes, i did check rewrite table, there is no such rule in there, basically this is happening when i try to do post request  on this route /webhooks it redirects me to / with 302 response

Comment: updates my answer